# Django runserver on Chromebook (Crostini)

Tags: django, chromebook, crostini

I'm using a Chromebook HP 11 G5 EE and try to develop with Django.
I use Crostini (Linux terminal into Chrome OS with no developper mode).
I've created a virtualenv inside my home directory and installed with pip all my requirements.

When I try to do (with source bin/activate) :

```
./manage.py runserver
```

It returns me :

Performing system checks...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 28, 2019 - 20:02:11
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: You don't have permission to access that port.
```

I'd try to set parameters like 0.0.0.0:8000, penguin.linux.test:8000, to change ports, I've got the same error.

Is someone had the same issue and fixed it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try to access your django service from your Chromebook using a non-Chrome browser, e.g. Firefox for Android?  ChomeOS, I believe, partitions Android apps from Chrome, but at least on my Samsung Chromebook Pro, Android apps can interact with each other.  So I've run node.js/Express processes from Termux and interacted with them at 127.0.0.1 and localhost from Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting in the full error message you got using port 8000?

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 28, 2019 - 20:17:58
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: You don't have permission to access that port.